Discrete measure on $M^1(G)$
I consider the group (for the addition) $M^1(G)$ of signed and finite Radon measure on the locally compact topological group $G$. Now I define the subset
$$
M_{d}^{1}(G) = \{\mu\in M^1(G) : \mu = \sum_{k}\beta_k\delta_{g_k}, \sum_{k}\lvert\beta_k\rvert < \infty \}
$$
Such measures are called discrete. Initially I wanted to prove that if $\mu,\mu'\in M_{d}^{1}(G)$ then $\mu + \mu'\in M_{d}^{1}(G)$. I Tried to take the simplest case possible i.e. $\mu = \beta_1\delta_{g_1}$ and $\mu' = \beta_2\delta_{g_2}$, however I don't see how to gather this together. I first thought to something like $\delta_{g_1 + g_2}$ or something making use of the group structure but the elements of my sigma algebra are not necessarily subgroup so I cannot exploit this.
Thus, I think it is false (unless adding hypotheses?) but I would like to have your confirmation.
Thank you a lot
